# Regex for IP within a text line

Tags: regex, ipv6

I would like to get the IPv6 or IPv4 addressees from a text line as the following one

> TST: 20141104-03:03:56 Management - Switch to IP6Fast -> The provided
>   IP gd66:7::y4u0:345:4t7j:af is not IPv4, not switching
>
> TST: 20141104-03:03:56 Management - Switch to IP4Fast -> The provided
>   IP 192.168.10.1 is not IPv6, not switching

My regular expression can identify the IP addresses, both IPv6 and IPv4,  but only the one for IPv4 works with nearby text, the one for IPv6 doesn´t recognize the IPv6 address if there is text sourroundig it. How could I fix that aspect?

Thanks in advance,

My regular expression are these ones (first likne for IPv4 and the rest for Ipv6)

```
((\\b(?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}\\b)|
(\\b^(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))|::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))|(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))|(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){,2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){,3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){,4}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){,5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){,6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::)$)\\b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IPv4 regex doesn't actually work since it would allow something like 333.444.555.666 which is invalid for an IPv4 address.  Something like this works better (this is PCRE regex):

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\b
```

As far as IPv6 goes, are you trying to capture uncompressed, compressed, and/or mixed?  It can get very complex.

The reason your regex for IPv6 is not matching is that you have wrapped it in `^` and `$` that specify the start and and of a string.  That prevents any string with extra stuff around from matching.

Comment: To be honest @ndarkness probably doesn't need to check for accurate IP addresses, but is just looking to find "IP-Like strings in the text". Also, your regex doesn't support leading zeros (i.e. 127.000.000.001) which may be treated as a valid IP address - [Raymond Chen shows one here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/22/603788.aspx)

Comment: Leading zeros are a bad thing. They are often interpreted as octal numbers, and should not be used in IPv4 addresses. Most IPv4 regular expressions don't include them. The IPv4 regex that I provided will not allow invalid IPv4 addresses, and that was my only point.